# Set sprites to descend from greater than window size

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am working on a small game in pygame and I have enemies flying down from the top of the screen towards the player. However, currently I am only able to make them descend from 0 on the y scale, which makes the waves of enemeies really short and compact. I have this code:

```
for i in range(10):
    block = Block(BLACK)
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(800)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(100)
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)
```

Is there any way I can make it so that they descend from above the screen height so that my the waves of enemies are much longer?

Heres my entire code incase anyone could shed some light on this:

http://pastebin.com/wrNUwD9q

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the enemies to start at a negative y value.

I would maybe change `block.rect.y = random.randrange(100)` to `block.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, 100)` if you want some of the enemies to come from offscreen.

You could also make it something like `block.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, 0)` if you want all of the enemies to come from offscreen.

You can basically imagine that the canvas you can place sprites on extends beyond the viewable area, so you can place things outside of the viewable area if you want them to appear from offscreen.